# java jpanel not functioning

Tags: java, user-interface, applet

I'm trying to make a 4x5 Grid within a JPanel that is on a BORDERLAYOUT in EAST... soo here is pic:

[image]

Here is the code:

> setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
>
> JPanel invOne = new JPanel(newGridLayout(4,5));
>
> JPanel game = new JPanel();
>
> ```
>  add("Center",invOne);
>
>  add("East", game);
>
>  add("South", c);
> ```
>
> for (int i = 0,  j = 20;  i < 20;  i = i+1, j = j-1)  {
>
> invOne.add(new JButton("SLOT " + j));
>
> }

As you can see the invinventory slots are OVERLAPPING the game panel which should NOT happen because the game panel is in the CENTER  of the BorderLayout and the Inventory panel (invOne) is on the EAST of the BorderLayout so I don't know why it's overlapping...

help?

Comment: I gave you a link to the Swing tutorial on using Layout Managers. That is NOT how you add components to a panel using a BorderLayout. Download and run the demo programs to understand the proper way to do this. If you have problems then post your SSCCE (http://sscce.org) showing the problem.

Comment: From what I see in your code, the game panel is a east and the invOne in the center.

Comment: this is not the best way to add components using the BorderLayout, but the code is correct. The problem must be somewhere else, or/and this is the wrong code (game is East and not Center as described). I suspect the problem is with the definition of game or the way it is painted, but we need more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's `add(invOne, BorderLayout.CENTER);`. You should use constants from BorderLayout class instead of strings.

Comment: -1, This doesn't solve the problem. The OP was given a link to the Swing tutorial which shows the proper way to do this in a previous posting. He was also given a reminder to again read the tutorial.

Comment: @camickr: It did fix the problem he asked about, you can see it in his next post :) BTW, I tried looking for the post where you gave him a link to the tutorial before posting, but didn't find it.